# Crystal Reports: Table header on each page in section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with several subreports.  Each of these subreports has a section header, a "table header" (which is just a few textboxes that say the name of each column of the table) and a table.

If the table is multiple pages in length, though, it needs to display the "table header" at the top of each subsequent page.  It currently looks like this:

```
Section Header
--------------------------------
Col1 Col2 Col3
Data Data Data
Data Data Data

line break

Data Data Data
Data Data Data
```

But it needs to look like this:

```
Section Header
--------------------------------
Col1 Col2 Col3
Data Data Data
Data Data Data

line break

Col1 Col2 Col3
Data Data Data
Data Data Data
```

I'm no expert on Crystal Reports but I don't think I can make it a conditional page header, because it still needs to be under the section header on the first page.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using page headers instead of report headers

If you are using a group you can use: Report> Group Expert->Options->Options "Repeat Group Header On Each Page"

Comment: You mean instead of section headers I would use a page header that's only applicable for one page, and then the "table header" would be another page header that's only applicable for pages within the section?

Comment: Its been a while but I believe there are 3 kinds of headers: Report, Page, and group. I'm saying what ever header you are using make sure it is either a page header or if it is a group header that is has "repeat header on each page"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Section Header is actually the Group Header, you will not be able to lay it out the way you want it without some tweaking. You can use Page Headers which will show up at the top of every page, above the Group Header. You could add a second Group Header section and put your labels there, then in the Group Expert check "Repeat Group Header on every page, but that will also repeat the main Group Header. You could get creative, reset your page count each time the group changes and then doa conditional suppress on the main group header if the page number <> 1.

Hope that helps,

Chris